# Asynchronous Issue with createCustomerProfile in Sample Node.JS code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, authorize.net

Our goal is to integrate Authorize.NET into our application using the Node SDK sample code.

Node SDK: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-node

Recommended Sample Code: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-node/tree/ef9e5c2d9e0379b5f47a0ebcb6847e711fe196ef

I am trying to create a customer payment profile and while I am able to create a customer profile successfully and receive a successful response from the API call 
CustomerProfilesModule.createCustomerProfile, the remainder of my auth.controller.js runs before I get the API result. All of the create-customer-profile.js runs up until the ctrl.execute() runs, then the console.log("xxx") in auth.controller.js runs before grabbing the API result.

I understand this is a synchronous issue with my code, but I don't know how to solve this. I am using the sample code authorize.NET provided, however the code is using the real data from my app rather than the sample data. I am more than happy to provide further information upon request and really appreciate any help!

```js
// AUTH.CONTROLLER.JS
const httpStatus = require("http-status");
const ApiContracts = require("authorizenet").APIContracts;
const ApiControllers = require("authorizenet").APIControllers;
const SDKConstants = require("authorizenet").Constants;
const User = require("../models/user.model");
const RefreshToken = require("../models/refreshToken.model");
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
const { jwtExpirationInterval } = require("../../config/vars");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const CustomerProfilesModule = require("../utils/authorizeNet/CustomerProfiles");

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userData = req.body;

    let customerProfileResult =
      await CustomerProfilesModule.createCustomerProfile(userData);
    console.log(
      "❌ ❌ ❌ ❌ ❌ customerProfile Result ",
      customerProfileResult
    );

    if (!userData || userData.error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      const { isTrial } = userData;

      const user = await new User(userData).save();

      const token = generateTokenResponse(user, user.token());


      res.status(httpStatus.CREATED);
      return res.json({ token, user });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return next(User.checkDuplicateEmail(error));
  }
};



//////////



// CREATE-CUSTOMER-PROFILE.JS 
var ApiContracts = require("authorizenet").APIContracts;
var ApiControllers = require("authorizenet").APIControllers;
var utils = require("../utils.js");

async function createCustomerProfile(user) {
  console.log(" user parameter", user);
  var merchantAuthenticationType =
    new ApiContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
  merchantAuthenticationType.setName(process.env.AUTHORIZE_NET_API_LOGIN_KEY);
  merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(
    process.env.AUTHORIZE_NET_TRANSACTION_KEY
  );

  var creditCard = new ApiContracts.CreditCardType();
  creditCard.setCardNumber(user.cardNumber);
  if (user.cardExpiry.length > 4) {
    creditCard.setExpirationDate(
      `${user.cardExpiry.slice(0, 1)}${user.cardExpiry.slice(3, 4)}`
    );
  } else {
    creditCard.setExpirationDate(user.cardExpiry);
  }

  console.log("creditCard", creditCard);

  var paymentType = new ApiContracts.PaymentType();

  paymentType.setCreditCard(creditCard);

  var customerAddress = new ApiContracts.CustomerAddressType();

  customerAddress.setFirstName(user.firstName);
  customerAddress.setLastName(user.lastName);
  customerAddress.setAddress(user.mailingAddress);
  customerAddress.setCity(user.mailingCity);
  customerAddress.setState(user.mailingState);
  customerAddress.setZip(user.mailingZip);
  customerAddress.setCountry("USA");
  customerAddress.setPhoneNumber(user.userPhone);

  var customerPaymentProfileType =
    new ApiContracts.CustomerPaymentProfileType();
  customerPaymentProfileType.setCustomerType(
    ApiContracts.CustomerTypeEnum.INDIVIDUAL
  );
  customerPaymentProfileType.setPayment(paymentType);
  customerPaymentProfileType.setBillTo(customerAddress);

  var paymentProfilesList = [];
  paymentProfilesList.push(customerPaymentProfileType);
  console.log(
    "paymentProfilesList",
    paymentProfilesList
  );

  var customerProfileType = new ApiContracts.CustomerProfileType();
  customerProfileType.setMerchantCustomerId(
    "M_" + utils.getRandomString("cust")
  );
  customerProfileType.setDescription(
    `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}'s Account'`
  );
  customerProfileType.setEmail(user.userEmail);
  customerProfileType.setPaymentProfiles(paymentProfilesList);

  var createRequest = new ApiContracts.CreateCustomerProfileRequest();
  createRequest.setProfile(customerProfileType);
  createRequest.setValidationMode(ApiContracts.ValidationModeEnum.TESTMODE);
  createRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);

  var ctrl = new ApiControllers.CreateCustomerProfileController(
    createRequest.getJSON()
  );

  // All above code is ran when  CustomerProfilesModule.createCustomerProfile(userData) is executed in auth.controller.js
  // However the following line (line 130 in auth.controller.js) is ran before the below ctrl.execute() code is completed
  //
  //    console.log("❌ ❌ ❌ ❌ ❌ customerProfile Result ", customerProfileResult);
  //
  // All the above code is executed before that console.log("❌ ❌ ❌") statement above, however the below code doesn't run before that console.log
  // I'd like the below code to execute before the remaining register route is finished, but just don't know what is going on!

  ctrl.execute(async function () {
    var apiResponse = await ctrl.getResponse();
    console.log("apiResponse", apiResponse);

    var response = new ApiContracts.CreateCustomerProfileResponse(apiResponse);
    console.log("response", response);

    //pretty print response
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));

    if (response != null) {
      if (
        response.getMessages().getResultCode() ==
        ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK
      ) {
        console.log(
          "Successfully created a customer profile with id: " +
            response.getCustomerProfileId()
        );
      } else {
        console.log("Result Code: " + response.getMessages().getResultCode());
        console.log(
          "Error Code: " + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode()
        );
        console.log(
          "Error message: " + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText()
        );
        return {
          error:
            "Error message: " +
            response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText(),
        };
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Null response received");
      return { error: "Null response received" };
    }
  });
}

module.exports.createCustomerProfile = createCustomerProfile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl.execute is a method handling an IIFE function which is not called.
IIFE functions are invoked as soon as is defined.

You will not be able to run IIFE before declaration.

Possible solution:

Try to create a callback route inside register route and then exclude the IIFE to get the response from the callback inside register before actual route finished.

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand your code enough to know how you want it to work. But from my understanding the `console.log` is running between when you get a call from the api and after you get the api, putting it in an awkward phase.

How asynchronous code works is that JavaScript will let the asynchronous function run, leave, do something else in the meantime, and get back to it when it is done.

The issue I see with your code is that `createCustomerProfile` doesn't return anything when it's done. You have a function that returns a promise of void. First off, that's a problem because you're using the return value of the function in `console.log()`.

I highly recommend to promisify so that it properly resolves or has an error, which when you're working with API's you're likely to encounter potential errors in which you want to handle that.

You say the `console.log()` is being called before `ctrl.execute()` but I don't even see where it is being executed at all because I don't see it in the `createCustomerProfile` function.